# C=O bond length comparison among cyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one and cyclohex‐3‐en‐1‐one

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

[image: 1: cyclohex‐2‐en‐1‐one; 2: cyclohex‐3‐en‐1‐one]

I can see that in the first case a resonance would occur, and in the second case, there would be no resonance effect. I have read the fact that resonance reduces bond length due to partial double bond character.

According to that, shouldn't the $\ce{C=O}$ bond length in **1** be lesser than that in **2**? The answer in my book is that the $\ce{C=O}$ bond in **1** is longer (reason is simply given as: "Resonance"). Could someone help me understand what's going on here?

Comment: Think of it this way: resonance shortens some bonds and elongates others, all that due to partial double bond character.

Comment: @IvanNeretin How to know which are shortened and which become longer?

Comment: Why, that's simple. What is shorter, a single or a double bond?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Ahh i think i got it. In case 2, it is a double bond, no partial character, thus shorter and in case 1, it is a partial double bond character only, so it will be longer relative to the 2nd case. Is my reasoning accurate?

Comment: Yes.$\mathstrut$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case **1** has partial double bond character (due to resonance) while case **2** has total double bond character of the C-O bond. So, relative to case **2**, the C-O bond length in case **1** is longer.